# FPDF add new fonts with central europe encoding

Tags: encoding, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to encode some characters like Š,Č.
I added new font `AbhayaLibre-Regular` I generate the font files [http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/make.php](https://www.fpdf.org/makefont/make.php) . I used

```
 ISO-8859-2 (Central Europe)
```

to generate font files
but still I get strange encode chars:

> PlaÄilo odkupnine

expected result:

> Plačilo odkupnine

Comment: Is your string really encoded in ISO-8859-2?

Comment: I created this font 'AbhayaLibre-Regular' using ISO-8859-2. in the website  http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/make.php

Comment: Yes but then you need to use strings encoded in ISO-8859-2 when you create the PDF, otherwise you get an encoding mismatch.